# sum Overlapping interval algorithm (edit)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

i have a problem i need to get the union of the interval by O(n *logn)

i have array that simulate a Straight line with points,

in need to sum all the overlapping points

example:
(after sorting ,(i need to sort by the left side  i did that))
Interval[] arr=[1, 3], [2, 4.5] ,[3.5 , 5] , [6, 9] , [7, 8]

if [1,3] overlapping with [2 ,4.5] (2 between [1,3] ) the sum will be:

```
sum = 4.5-1= 3.5
```

(exp: [1, 3] [2, 4.5] ,[3.5 , 5] => on the some line (overlapping sum = 5-1 = 4)),

or

if [6, 9],[7, 8] overlapping ([7,8] between [6,9])so the "sum" will be 9-6=3

the total sum  will be 4+3= 7(union ).

```
enter code here public static double unionLength(Interval [] arr){
    double sum=0;
    int i=0;
    double start,end;
    double max=0 ,maxtemp=0;
    Sort.mergeSort2(arr);
    if(arr.length>1){
        start=arr[0].left;
        while(i<arr.length){
            if(arr[i+1].left<=arr[i].right){
                max=Math.max(arr[i+1].right, arr[i].right);
                i++;
            }
            else{
                sum=sum+(max-start);                    
                i++;
                start=arr[i].left;
            }
            if(i>=arr.length-1){
                max=Math.max(arr[i].right, arr[i-1].right);
                sum=sum+(max-start);
                break;
            }

        }

    }
    else{
        sum=arr[0].right-arr[0].left;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

how can i improve it ?

Comment: If you will be performing multiple queries on the same set of data, how about an Interval tree? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Construction

Comment: can't use Interval tree

Comment: Your problem description is totally unclear. Please clarify it by formalizing it better and giving better examples